# What happens when multiple scanf()s are included in a single for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

I have written a code for comparing the triplet problem. The problem statement is:

Input: 2 arrays of size 3

Task is to find their comparison points by comparing `a[0]` with `b[0]`, `a[1]` with `b[1]`, and `a[2]` with `b[2]`.

If `a[i] > b[i]`, then Alice is awarded point. If `a[i] < b[i]` then Bob is awarded the point. If `a[i] == b[i]` then neither person receives the point. Comparison points is the total points the person earned. Given `a` and `b` determine their respective comparison points.

The code I wrote is:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void main(){   
       int i, alice[3], bob[3];
       int a = 0;
       int b = 0;
                                                                                                                                          
       for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                 scanf("%d", &alice[i]);
       }
       for(i=0; i<3; i++){
                 scanf("%d", &bob[i]); 
       }
       for(i=0; i<3; i++){ 
                if(alice[i] > bob[i])  
                       a++; 
                else if (alice[i] < bob[i]) 
                       b++;
       }   
      printf("%d %d", a, b);
 }
```

But when I put the two scanf()s in one line,

```
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){    
             scanf("%d", &alice[i]); 
             scanf("%d", &bob[i]); 
  }
```

The output is like 2 1 or 1 2 for all the inputs. Is it wrong to put two `scanf()` calls in a single for loop? I couldn't understand what is the reason behind this problem? Would someone kindly explain the reason?

Comment: It will read them in a different order. Which one is correct depends on what order the input is in.

Comment: Try `printf("enter Alice's value #%d\n", i); scanf("%d", &alice[i]);` `printf("enter Bob's value #%d\n", i); scanf("%d", &bob[i]); `

Comment: Thank you so much @interjay. Got solved.

Comment: Thank you so much @pmg. Got solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version reads three values for `alice` and then three values for `bob`.  The second version reads one value for `alice`, then one for `bob`, and repeats that 3 times.

If the entered numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, then in the first example, `alice` gets 1, 2, 3 while `bob` gets 4, 5, 6; in the second example, `alice` gets 1, 3, 5 while `bob` gets 2, 4, 6.  Quite different results.

Comment: Note that a good step when trying to understand what's going on is to print the input arrays after the data is read: `printf("Alice:"); for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf(" %d", alice[i]); putchar('\n'); printf("Bob:"); for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf(" %d", bob[i]); putchar('\n');` This would show the difference between the two ways of entering the data. The code in those two loops could be refactored into a function `void print_array(const char *tag, size_t n, int array[n]) { printf("%s:", tag); for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) printf(" %d", array[i]); putchar('\n'); }`, called twice.